# How to force loading the current version of an offline-able web app?

Tags: caching, webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm doing a tiny offline-able web app / PWA. It's meant to be opened from a home screen icon and mimic a regular app by loading entirely from a cache when offline.

The app is written using Vue and to accomplish the above I'm just using their PWA template and whatever it generates. To the best of my knowledge what this does is set up [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) using the [GenerateSW plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#generatesw_plugin_1) to precache everything in the Webpack build, and registers it using [register-service-worker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/register-service-worker). That is, I have fairly little control out of the box over the fine details, it's meant to be a turnkey solution.

That said, I'm not sure how to actually load a new build of the application when it's available. The above can detect this - the generated SW registration file with my changes looks like this:

```
import debug from 'debug';
import { register } from 'register-service-worker';


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready(...args) {
      log('App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n', ...args);
    },
    cached(...args) {
      log('Content has been cached for offline use.', ...args);
    },
    updated(...args) {
      log('New content is available; please refresh.', ...args);
    },
    offline(...args) {
      log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.', ...args);
    },
    error(error, ...args) {
      log('Error during service worker registration:', error, ...args);
    }
  });
}
```

When I make a new build of the application, and I refresh the app in a browser, the `updated()` callback is executed, but nothing else is done. When I tried adding:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

which should be a forced refresh, I just get a refresh loop. I'm assuming this is because the service worker cache is completely independent from the browser cache and unaffected by things like the above or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. (Which makes the "please refresh" rather misleading.)

Since this is going to mimic a native app, and it's supposed to be a simple line-of-business tool, I don't really need to do anything more complicated than immediately reload to the new version of the app when an update is available. How can I achieve this?

Comment: caches, SW are complicated . 'app' shutdown needed prior to SW cache replacement... https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68

Comment: @RobertRowntree - I appreciate that it is and have the migraine to show for it, but also there will literally never be multiple tabs of this running on a device if used as intended so I’d rather avoid having to replace the generated SW with a handwritten one if I possibly can because there’s only that much time I should spend on delivering this.

Comment: my takeaway from the link... u can go with what workbox gives you... the spec and the implementation pretty much force u to notify the user "plz refresh to get NEW SW" if u whanna force SW re-register, re-activate Without the 24HR delay from the spec   https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle

Comment: my point is that even if I refresh I'm not getting the new code

Comment: I hash a few random bytes and punt them into the page footer on every build and it doesn't change until I clear the app storage from devtools

Comment: to be fair this kind of helped as input because it turns out that when the existing instance of the app is closed - i.e. not just reloaded - the next time it starts it will switch over to the new loaded code. It's just so very confusing especially with the default code you're given and this is documented nowhere omg.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the behaviour I've observed is that the update does happen automatically, it's just not obvious as to what the exact sequence of events is. I'll try to describe my best understanding of how the generated service worker works in the installed PWA scenario. I'll speak in terms of "app versions" for simplicity, because the mental model behind this is closer to how apps, not webpages work:

- You deploy v1 of your application to a server, install / precache it on a device, and run it for the first time.
- When you suspend and resume your app, it does not hit your servers at all.
- The app will check for an update when it's either cold-started, or you reload the page, i.e. using the pull down gesture on Android.
  *(Possibly also periodically as the cached version goes stale, but I haven't checked this.)*
- Say you've deployed v2 of your app in the meantime. Reloading an instance of v1 of the app will find this update, and precache it.
  *(One reason why prompting the user to reload doesn't seem to make sense. Whatever the reloading is meant to accomplish has already happened.)*
- **Reloading** an instance of v1 again does absolutely nothing. The app remains running between reloads, and you'll just get v1 afterwards.
  *(Reason number two why prompting the user to reload is pointless - it's not what causes a new version of an app to load.)*
- However, next time you **cold start** your app - e.g. nuke it from the task switcher and reopen - v2 of your app will be loaded and I'm guessing v1 will get cleaned out. That is, your app must fully shut down so an update will load.

In short, for an application to be updated from v1 to v2, the following steps need to occur:

1. Deploy v2 to server
2. Refresh instance of v1 on device, or shut down and reopen the app.
3. Shut down and reopen the app (again).